# Opening file select when clicking on a div not file input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I wanted to design an image uploader. For selecting an image we do this:

```
<input type="file" />
```

but I don't want to use that regular input, I have a `div` and I want that when user clicks on that, file selecting dialog opens and after that everything continues in standard way.

I want to use `Angular.js` rather than `jQuery` if possible because my project is under `Angular.js`

Answer (score 31):

You dont need javascript to do this, please dont look at the inline style

```
<div style="position: relative; border: 1px solid red; width: 50px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;" > 
    Open
    <input type="file" style="opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height:100%;" />
</div>
```

Note you need to add more crossbrowser opacity lines

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/yp2dykn5/

**Edited** this seams to be a populair question/answer. 
So i updated this answer with the information below including cross browser opacity lines support.

```css
div {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 50px;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}

.file_upload {
   opacity: 0.0;

   /* IE 8 */
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

   /* IE 5-7 */
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 
   /* Netscape or and older firefox browsers */
   -moz-opacity: 0.0;

   /* older Safari browsers */
   -khtml-opacity: 0.0;

   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
     Open
     <input type="file" class="file_upload" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15):

I would give the `<input>` element the CSS property `display: none;` Then I would apply whatever styling needed to fit your situation to a `<label>` element linked to the `<input>` through the use of the [`for` attribute (link to w3school page)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp). In all browsers I know of, clicking on the `<label>` of an `<input>` works the same as clicking on the `<input>`.

This solution only using CSS and does not use JavaScript. The `<label>` can be styled in any way that a `<div>` can be styled.

**Edit:** I elaborated on my answer since I noticed the complexity of the top answer.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.file_upload {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="getFile1" class="file_upload">Open File</label>
<input type="file" id="getFile1" class="hide"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion with Jquery would be to keep a div and an `input[type="file"]`.The input should be made hidden and trigger the click of input using JQuery, like below

**HTML**

```
<div id="id">Open</div>
<input id="yourinputname" type="file" name="yourinputname" style="display: none;" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#id').on('click', function() {
    $('#yourinputname').trigger('click');
});
```

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/QVAC7/201/)

Answer (score 1):

**My File upload form with bootstrap and fontawesome**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/fontawesome-all.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm p-4">
       <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Upload File</h4>
       <div class="card-body">
         <h2 class="card-title">

           <label style="cursor: pointer;" for="file_upload">
             <span class="text-muted fa fa-upload"></span>
           </label>
           <input type="file" id="file_upload" class="d-none"/>

         </h2>
       </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react: (*sorry for the hideous indentation, stack would not let me format it correctly*)

```
#getFile {
                display: none;
              }

<label htmlFor="getFile">
                <FontIcon iconName="photo" className="uploadIcon"/>
                <input type="file" id="getFile" />
                </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react and I wanted the file input to open when the enclosing div was clicked so I created a function:

```
function handleZoneClicked() {
    document.getElementById('dropzone-file-input').click();
  }
```

And the added the id to the div, and the made the input's display none.